# Search API Views - Show search string in text

Tags: views, search

I created a view to display my indexed data, anything works just fine. What I now want to achieve is, that only the part of the bodytext is displayed, that contains the search string. The default drupal search engine can do this, but I have no idea how to achieve this using views.

Someone got an idea how to do that?

Greetings

SG

Answer (score 0):

[Views Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_search) module will work for you.

Comment: This is just for Drupal 6